# System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16 in iis 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

i have a login method writen in visual studio 2012. The code of the login is:

```
public DataSet Login(string UserName, string Password)
{
    DataSet Message = new DataSet();
    Tbl_Users User = new Tbl_Users();
    string ClientIP = Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    DataSet result = User.Login(UserName, Password, ClientIP);
    if (Int16.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) < 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = Message.Tables.Add("results");
        dt.Columns.Add("status");
        dt.Columns.Add("results");
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "-1";
        row[1] = ErrorFinder.SQlErrorHandeling(Int32.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()));
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    else
        Message = result;
    return Message;
}
```

when i execute it in the visual studio, every thing is ok. but when i publish the website by visual studio and put it in the windows seven iis, i got this error:

```
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.
at System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at Service.Login(String UserName, String Password)
```

i dont know what is wrong with the published website?

Comment: On which value and which line exactly?

Comment: You are doing `Int16.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()`, what is the value in that cell? Are you sure it fits in an Int16? It can only hold a value in the range -32,768 to 32,767

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that `result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()` contains larger value which a Int16 can hold. All the types of integers has different range of following storage capacity:

```
Int 16 -- (-32768 to +32767)

Int 32 -- (-2,147,483684 to +2,147,483683)

Int 64 -- (-9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your development data table have smaller values that compatible with Int 16. Which is why you don't get error. Replace 16 with 32.

```
if (Int16.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) < 0)
```

to

```
if (Int32.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) < 0)
```

or you can even make it simpler

```
if (int.Parse(result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) < 0)
```