# Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, registration

I am trying to create a registration page, however encountered an additional error!
What I'm trying to achieve is transfer the codes that are entered by the user into the database.
However, I could not achieve the objective that I want to due to an error encountered after clicking on the submit button.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Error Message:
Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to     numeric. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Registration.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\TemporarySter\Registration.aspx.cs:line 80 ClientConnectionId:c3fd51e0-9dc7-49ba-ab88-313267504802
```

My SQL Database codes

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client] (
    [ClientNo]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [cFirstName]   NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [cLastName]    NCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [cD.O.B]       DATE           NOT NULL,
    [cCompanyName] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [cAddress]     NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [cCity]        NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [cZipCode]     NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [cPhoneNo] NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
    [cFax]         NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
    [cEmail]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [cUsername]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [cPassword]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ClientNo] ASC)
);
```

My aspx.cs codes for the registration page

```
  using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static readonly string scriptErrorUsername =
        "<script language =\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Error - Username is already taken! Please key in another Username\");\n" +
        "</script>";
    static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
        "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Your account has been successfully created - Thank You!\");\n" +
        "</script>";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Desktop\TemporarySter\App_Data\legitdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from Client where cUserName= '" + userTB.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("Username is already taken! Please choose another username.");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Desktop\TemporarySter\App_Data\legitdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            conn.Open();
            Type csType = this.GetType();
            SqlCommand com;
            SqlDataReader rdr;
            string strSQLSelect = "SELECT cUsername FROM Client ORDER BY cUsername";         
            com = new SqlCommand(strSQLSelect, conn);
            rdr = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                if (userTB.Text == (string)rdr["cUsername"])
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorUsername);
                    conn.Close();
                    rdr.Close();
                    return;
                }
            }


            string insertQuery = "insert into Client (cFirstName, cLastName, [cD.O.B], cCompanyName, cAddress, cCity, cZipCode, cPhoneNo, cFax, cEmail, cUsername, cPassword) values (@firstname,@lastname,@dob,@companyname,@address,@city,@zipcode,@phoneno,@fax,@email,@username,@password)";
            com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnameTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnameTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateTB.Text.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", companyTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addressTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", postalcodeTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", contactnumberTB.Text.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", faxTB.Text.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passTB.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("ClientLogin.aspx");
            Response.Write("Congratulations! Your registration is successful!");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);
            conn.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }


}
    protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect("~/Registration.aspx", true);

    }

}
```

Comment: PhoneNumbers are strings not numbers. Change your database columns (also FAX) to be nvarchar. (size 20  should be enough to accomodate international prefixes, area code and whatever your user throws here). Don't follow the advice to convert your input to a number. It is wrong....

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but for posterity... Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` and should each be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Declare Phone No as Numeric Field So You need to Convert Your Text into Integer

```
 [cPhoneNo] NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL
 [cFax]     NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL
```

Use like this:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", Convert.ToInt32(contactnumberTB.Text));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", Convert.ToInt32(faxTB.Text));
```

**[STOP USING ADD WITH VALUES](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)**

Comment: Hi sir, obtained another error.

Error:System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16. at System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Convert.ToInt16(String value) at Registration.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Desktop\TemporarySter\Registration.aspx.cs:line 74

Comment: @SarahCollins what is value of `cPhoneNo` you are putting into TextBox

Comment: I have set a constraint to allow only 8 numbers.

Example : 88888888

Comment: @SarahCollins I updated. You need to Use `Convert.ToInt32` because Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161155/system-overflowexception-value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-int16-i

Comment: While your answer is technically correct it is logically wrong. Phonenumbers are not number but strings. The OP should change the datacolumn type not convert the input to a number. And what is the point to add ToString to the Text (a string) property?

Comment: @Steve Your are right but OP said ` Example : 88888888 ` in above comments

Answer (score 1):

The phone number value is a string in your cs:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", contactnumberTB.Text.ToString());
```

In your table it is numeric:

```
[cPhoneNo] NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
```

[Edit:]
You should update the datatype in your table.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct it is logically wrong. Phonenumbers are not number but strings. The OP should change the datacolumn type not convert the input to a number. And what is the point to convert a string to a string (Text.ToString()???)

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes in your code

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneno", Convert.ToDouble(contactnumberTB.Text.ToString()));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@@fax", Convert.ToDouble(faxTB..Text.ToString()));
```

You need to make changes because your trying to insert string value in numeric field.
By defining this you you are declaring in db that following fields are are numeric and hence application will fail with string value. And is why above change is required to make numeric value to double.

```
[cPhoneNo] NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
[cFax]         NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
```